# Pset4 recover fails check50 test

Tags: c, jpeg, recovery, cs50

I'm struggling with the CS50 course **pset4 "recover"**. The code works, but when I test it (check50), it shows two errors:

```
:( recovers middle files correctly
:( recovers last file correctly
```

[Here's the sandbox](https://sandbox.cs50.net/checks/a1c0ba8918d84ef3b2ab969e6f43ff42).
Could anyone help me with it, please? :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BLOCK 512

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc !=2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./copy infile\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char* infile = argv[1];
    FILE* card = fopen(infile, "r");
    if(card == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open %s!\n", infile);
        return 2;
    }

    FILE* img = NULL;

    int counter = 0;
    char image[8]; 

    BYTE data[BLOCK];
    //checking if the end of the card is reached
    while(fread(&data, sizeof(BLOCK), 1, card) !=0)
    {
        //checking if it's a new jpeg
        if(data[0] == 0xff && data[1] == 0xd8 && data[2] == 0xff && (data[3] & 0xf0)==0xe0)
        {
            //if it's not the first new jpeg, close the previous 
            if(img !=NULL)
            {
                fclose(img);
            }

            sprintf(image, "%03i.jpg", counter);
            img = fopen(image, "w");
            if(img == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open %s!\n", image);
                fclose(card);
                return 3;
            }
            counter++;

        }
        if(img !=NULL)
        {
            fwrite(&data, sizeof(BLOCK), 1, img);
        }
    } 

    fclose(img);
    fclose(card);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of questions here on SO with the [tag:cs50] tag and some of those are about the JPEG recovery exercise, and there are probably answers in amongst those to help you.  There's also the [CS50](http://cs50.stackexchange.com/) site that might help.  One problem for anyone who tries to help is getting hold of the data; another is testing the results.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I found an error, finally!